# how to call function in c++ from delphi compiled dll

Tags: c++, qt, dll

I have a problem with using dll library made in delphi. I don't have sources for it - only dll and interface. I want to import it in my c++ program. I don't need to use QT for loading (but it would be probably the best option as ) - also standard Windows api is applicable.

First, **interface of the dll:**

```
Unit VPInterface;
interface

type
 TSignal     = array of double;
 ShortVector = array[0..11] of double;

function VP(s: TSignal): ShortVector; stdcall;
 stdcall external 'VoicePrint.dll' name 'VP';

implementation

End {VPInterface.pas}.
```

**The QT version:**

```
typedef double* (*VPFunct)(double[]);
vector<double> v_double;
// put some values in v_double
QLibrary lib("VoicePrint.dll");
VPFunct vpfunct = (VPFunct) lib.resolve("VP");
if (vpfunct) {
  double * res = vpfunct(&v_double[0]);
}
```

1. The function is called and some output is returned but it's rubbish. As you can see I passed internal vector's array (&v_double[0]). I tried with double array on stack but the function haven't finished. Can someone explain it why?
2. Why I don't see correct results? I have similar code in C# and it works:

   ```
   namespace WAT_DLL_TEST
   {
   public class VoicePrint
   {
       [DllImport("VoicePrint.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Ansi, EntryPoint = "VP", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.StdCall)]
       [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Struct)]
       public static extern ShortVector VP(double[] signal);


       [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Explicit, Size = 48)]
       public unsafe struct ShortVector
       {
           [FieldOffset(0)]
           public fixed double m_buffer[6];
       }

   }
   }
   ```

May a structure be the actual problem?

And here is my code for running it using windows api:

```
HINSTANCE hinstDLL;
VPFunct myFunct;
BOOL fFreeDLL;

hinstDLL = LoadLibrary(L"VoicePrint.dll");
if (hinstDLL != NULL)
{
    myFunct = (VPFunct) GetProcAddress(hinstDLL, "VP");
    if (myFunct != NULL) {
        double * dptr = myFunct(&v_double[0]);
        for(int i=0; i<11; i++)
            cout << dptr[i] << endl;
    }
    fFreeDLL = FreeLibrary(hinstDLL);
}
```

Thanks for any help.

Comment: **I am using mingw 4.4 with qt 4.8.**

Comment: VoicePrint.dll and s.txt is here: http://www.speedyshare.com/naVrr/lib.rar. s.txt defines doubles which need to be passed to the VP function.

Answer (score 0):

You should mention calling conversion in your `typedef`:

```
typedef double* (__stdcall *VPFunct)(double[]);
```

Invalid calling conversion leads to stack corruption. It can explain *every* incorrect behavior.

You can try to simulate Delphi dynamic array memory layout (mentioned [here](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/XE3/en/Internal_Data_Formats)) with the follwing code:

```
#pragma pack (push, 1)

template <uint32_t size>
struct DelphiArray
{
    uint32_t _refCounter;
    uint32_t _size;
    double array[size];
};
#pragma pack (pop)
```

Then call function using `DelphiArray` like this

```
DelphiArray<N> arr;
arr._refCounter = 1;
arr._size = N;
//fill arr.array here
myFunc(arr.array);
```

Comment: Does't work. I tried that and also tried: typedef double* (__stdcall *VPFunct)(double[]); I would say that the behavior is the same so maybe __stdcall is by default?

Comment: @waldek, Does C# function return correct data? Does it called as usual? According to [doc](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/XE3/en/Internal_Data_Formats), Delphi dynamic arrays have some nontrivial layout. You may need to simulate it. `__stdcall` is not default. `_cdecl` is default.

Comment: Yes, c# code works correctly. The problem is that each time I have different results in c++ so I guess I am reading wrong memory addresses or the layout of pointer is wrong or the data interpretation is wrong. I will try to wrap it around struct.

Comment: @waldek, it is more probable that problem occurs in passing argument to function due to complex dynamic array memory layout with negative indexes, than in return, that is static array, which is pretty straightforward (according the doc given). Note also, that while different results indicate problem, same results can not prove correctness.

Comment: Yes, I also cannot figure out why there is a problem in passing any local argument. I used libraries mainly under unix but I never had a problem with attributes.. What is more, I have an example app using the dll and the result is the same as in c#.

Comment: @waldek, did you try to pass 'prepared' array? With linux you have only 1 calling conversion, as far as I know.

Comment: Sorry, didn't see change. I tested it now:  `DelphiArray<2205> arr;
 arr._refCounter = 1;
 arr._size = 2205;
 for(int i =0; i<v_double.size(); i++) {
  arr.array[i] = v_double[i];
 }
 VPFunct vpfunct = (VPFunct) lib.resolve("VP");
 if (vpfunct) {
  double * dptr = vpfunct(arr.array);
 }` but the same behavior as when passing local variable - terminated when executing function.

Comment: for "template <uint32_t size> _stdcall struct DelphiArray" the same result

Comment: btw. C uses IEEE754 double precision format: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double_precision_floating-point_format in most cases while in the link provided by you the double layout exponent/fraction is different. Does it matter?

Comment: @waldek, they are coinside. You missinerpreted them. Also I tried to disassemble your `dll` and it looks like it has signature of `double* (__stdcall *)(double[], DelphiArray::arr*)` or `double* (__stdcall *VPFunct)(DelphiArray::arr, double[])`. But I'm a noob in disassembling.  I'm sure it uses that negative shifts from the doc.

Comment: Ok, probably I will be able to get source code but it will take some time. The most important question for me is why this works: typedef __stdcall double* (*VPFunct)(void*);vector<double> v_double; vpfunct((void*)(&v_double[0])); but this does not: double p_doubles[2205]; vpfunct((void*)(p_doubles)); with exactly the same values. I also tried passing statics but without any good results. Why the internal vector's array is so special?

Comment: @waldek, it is undefined behavior. vector allocates its array dynamically, and array is allocated statically. That makes difference.